# Error using viewstate (in a cluster?)

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am getting the follwing error,please tell me why this error is coming

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that `<machineKey>` configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: *Where* do you get this error?

Comment: How about posting a descriptive title + tags? And the question sucks too.

Comment: Multiple duplicates - searching on Validation of viewstate MAC failed gives over 10 pages of results

Answer (score 1):

this can happen when you post a form which in the meantime has been updated on the server, or the app has been recycled in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

By default Viewstate is generated based on the MAC address of the machine that the web server is running on - this can cause problems when load balancing web traffic across a web farm or cluster as there is a chance that a pages post back request might get processed by a different machine from the one that originally generated the viewstate token, which will cause the exception that you see above.

If your running a web farm / cluster then the answer is the `<machineKey>` configuration element - if you set this to the same algorithm / key for each of the machines then viewstate is generated based on this key instead of the MAC address of the machine, preventing the above problems.

[This blog article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000132.html) probably explains it better than I just did.